# ToggleButton Not Hitting Unchecked

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, togglebutton

I have recently just changed to a `ToggleButton` after doing research that they work like `RadioButtons` which is exactly what I need.

I have Storyboard animations on my Buttons and when I click they appear as an arrow to show that is the page your on like this:

[image]

But as you can see when I select them both that other one stays checked.

This is the code I have at the moment (for one of the buttons, the other is the same):

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnToDo" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Click="Button_Click" Height="29" Margin="0,132,0,0">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Image x:Name="Normal" Source="Images/Normal1.png" Width="281" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Image x:Name="Hover" Source="Images/Hover1.png" Opacity="0" Width="281" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <Image x:Name="Pressed" Source="Images/ben.png" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ButtonCheckedStoryboardBegin"
                                             Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseDownTimeLine}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ButtonUncheckedStoryboardEnd" 
                                             Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseUpTimeLine}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseUpTimeLine}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
```

My `MouseUpTimeLine`, `MouseDownTimeLine` and `MouseExitTimeLine` is this:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseDownTimeLine" >
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Pressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseUpTimeLine">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Pressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseExitTimeLine">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Normal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.00" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

**So I want the state to back to normal when it `IsChecked` is False, and this should be when another button `IsChecked`.**

Comment: So why not just edit a RadioButton template to look like that so you could specify a GroupName to only allow one to be checked at once like the behavior you desire? A ToggleButton isn't made like a RadioButton in that sense by default.

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm stupid sorry, I didn't even know that you could edit the template. I am new to all this. If you want to answer the question I can mark you having the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh no worries, everyone's bound to be new at something at some point. Anyhow like I said in the comment. The ToggleButton doesn't have the functionality you're looking for by default. Switching to a `RadioButton` and just styling it to look like your button would make life easier moving forward to provide the behavior you're after.

You can find information and default templates in the [MSN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and using Blend makes editing templates fairly easy, for your instance you could just plop a `RadioButton` on the designer, right-click it, and choose "edit template -> edit a copy" to add a copy of the control template to your view to edit to your hearts content.

Hope this helps, and if you run into anything along the way come on back and we'll get you sorted. Cheers